# jQuery search val() in multiple textboxes

Tags: jquery

What's the most efficient way to loop though all textboxes for searching for a specific value and not using `each()`?

Comment: Thats like saying whats the best way to walk without putting one leg in front of the other

Comment: why not using each ? any particular reason ?

Comment: yea, interesting in alternatives and performance

Comment: You can see the source of each() here, if you think you can provide something faster issue a pull request ;) https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: About performance, you won't get more performance not using each, just use good selectors

Comment: `.each` isn't likely the problem here. The best way to do this quickly is to limit the scope of input boxes you're traversing. Rather than `$('input')`, find the nearest common parent that your searchable input boxes share and descend from it: `$('.parent-element input')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always know your [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$('input:text[value="search text"]');  // exact

$('input:text[value*="search text"]'); // contains
```

Comment: +1 For avoiding `.each`, though I can't imagine this will be any faster since it will internally be implemented identically.

Comment: @meagar: Indeed, the internal implementation will be much the same, possibly with less call depth.

Answer (score 4):

Probably nothing wrong with using `.each`, as you're going to have to perform a loop no matter what, but you could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter), which may be shorter and a bit more expressive:

```
$("input").filter(function() { return this.value === "value"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use map instead, especially if you plan to store results from each textbox in an array as map does that by default (return value from the mapped method gets stored)

```
var resultArray = $.map(selection, function(item) { return xxxx; });
```